# How to deal with Leetcode Question "Check If Array Pairs Are Divisible by k"?

Tags: arrays, c

This is a question from Leetcode as below.

"Given an array of integers arr of even length n and an integer k.
We want to divide the array into exactly n / 2 pairs such that the sum of each pair is divisible by k.
Return true If you can find a way to do that or false otherwise."

The unfinished answer is listed below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int k = 5;
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int pairs = arrSize / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize && arr[i] != INT_MIN; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrSize && arr[j] != INT_MIN; j++) {
            if ((((long)arr[i] + arr[j]) % k) == 0) {
                pairs--;
                if (pairs == 0)
                    return true;
                arr[j] = INT_MIN;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Aside from the answer is right or wrong, I am confused by the usage of multiple conditions of for-loop.
I expect the outer for loop will run till `i == arrSize - 1`, but out of my expectation it stops at `i == 1` and `j == 2`.
I rewrite the condition from  `arr[i] != INT_MIN && i < arrSize` to `arr[i] != INT_MIN, i < arrSize`, then it works.
I prefer to `&&` but just can't figure out why it doesn't work.
I have no clue why it is.
Please shed light on it.
P.S. it is horrible to leave nothing but a negative review.

Comment: This program has undefined behavior due to reading beyond the end of the array.  You must do the end-of-array test _first_, before trying to access the array.  Look into _short-circuit evaluation_ of logical operators in C.

Comment: @paddy How come!  I'v controlled  the last index to `arrSize - 1`. Isn't it?

Comment: Sure, `i < arrSize` will evaluate to false when `i == arrSize`, but _before_ that happens you already tested `arr[i] != INT_MIN`, which means you read from `arr[arrSize]` and _THAT_ is undefined behavior.  Same in your `j`-loop.

Comment: @paddy you are right. But for now I just focus on the issue of multiple conditions in for-loop. That is what my question is.

Comment: The thing is, if you have undefined behavior in your program, and you ignore it then the problem you're chasing might just be a ghost.  I won't analyze your program any further than seeing undefined behavior.  That's where I stop.

Comment: @paddy fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current test `arr[i] != INT_MIN && i < arrSize` is incorrect as `arr[i]` is read before testing if `i` is a valid index.

Furthermore, you set the value to `INT_MIN` to specify they should be ignored, but the loop should continue. To implement this, you should write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == INT_MIN)
        continue;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arrSize; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == INT_MIN)
            continue;
        if ((((long long)arr[i] + arr[j]) % k) == 0) {
            pairs--;
            if (pairs == 0)
                return true;
            arr[j] = INT_MIN;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that there are problems in this approach:

- you modify the array, which might pose a problem
- `INT_MIN` is a legitimate `int` value, the algorithm fails if this value is present in the array at the start. Using a separate array to keep track of used entries is advisable.
- `arr[i] + arr[j]` might overflow: casting as `(long)` or `(long long)` might not suffice if the type of array element has the same size. You can avoid this problem rewriting the test as `if ((arr[i] % k + arr[j] % k) % k == 0)`, assuming `abs(k) <= INT_MAX / 2`.
- you can return false immediately if an unused entry does not have a matching entry.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check_array(int *arr, int arrSize, int k) {
    if (arrSize % 2)
        return false;
    bool used[arrSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
         used[i] = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        if (used[i])
            continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrSize; j++) {
            if (used[j])
                continue;
            if ((arr[i] % k + arr[j] % k) % k == 0) {
                used[i] = used[j] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!used[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    if (check_array(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), 5)) {
        printf("array matches criteria\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("array does not match criteria\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to **only ignore** values that you've set to `INT_MIN`. This can be written as for example

```
if (arr[i] == INT_MIN)
    continue;
```

What you've written instead is analogous to

```
if (arr[i] == INT_MIN)
    break;
```

It is **not** possible to write a `continue` into a simple condition expression.

The comma operator made it to *work* by actually *removing* this wrong logic - by discarding the value (though you're still accessing the array out of bounds, which leads to undefined behaviour).